# Same server, both SSL and non-SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, vhosts

Is it possible to have both SSL protocol and non-SSL protocol running on the same server in Apache 2.x?

So if I access `http://example.com` (non-SSL) and `https://example.com` (SSL) they would both be available.

If so, would I need to create a virtual host? How would this `VirtualHost` directive look like, could anyone give me an example? (Assuming I already have the certificates)

Comment: Do you want the SSL and non-SSL addresses to access the same site?

Comment: This is in no way related to programming and is offtopic here.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: server programming CAN be called programming in the traditional sense.

Comment: It's not programming, it's the configuration of an existing server application (Apache Httpd).

Comment: @EduardLuca No, it's not. Coffee making can't be called programming if coffee is often used for programming at night.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you simply add another VirtualHost for the same name on port 443 (HTTPS).
Set `SSLProtocol` to [whichever protocols](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) you wish to allow.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/your-domain-root
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/your-domain-root
    ServerName your-domain.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
    SSLProtocol TLSv1
</VirtualHost>
```